# Power BI push dataset data types

Tags: powerbi

I am using the Rest API to create a push dataset, one of my columns type is a date without time but I don't know the right data type for short date in Push dataset.

I tried to post this table schema

```
{
  "name": "SalesMarketing",
  "defaultMode": "Push",
  "tables": [
    {
      "name": "Product",
      "columns": [
        {
          "name": "ProductID",
          "dataType": "Int64"
        },
        
        {
          "name": "ManufacturedOn",
          "dataType": "Date"
        },
        {
          "name": "Sales",
          "dataType": "Int64",
          "formatString": "Currency"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I get this error

**Response Code: 400**

> {
> "error": {
> "code": "InvalidRequest",
> "message": "TOM deserialization failed for database sobe_wowvirtualserver|d90bcf80-ec36-4667-931b-22a619b371ac, Exception: Cannot convert value 'Date' to required type 'DataType'. Check path 'tables[0].columns[1].dataType', line 1, position 146."
> }
> }>
> Where do I find the supported data types for the push dataset?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you create a streaming dataset in Power BI, you can see that the only supported data types are `Text`, `Number` and `DateTime`:

[image]

When you are creating a dataset using the API, you use `string`, `Double`/`Int64` and `DataTime`.

Here you can see the list of data types supported by [Tabular Object Model (TOM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/data-types-supported-ssas-tabular?view=asallproducts-allversions#bkmk_data_types) and there is no type for dates without time part. You must use the format string to format the value to be shown as a date only.